# Travis-CI error compiling Storyboard (Compile Storyboard file LaunchScreen.storyboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, continuous-integration, travis-ci

My `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: objective-c

script: 
    xctool -project ProjectName. xcodeproj -scheme ProjectName build -sdk iphonesimulator
```

While Travis-CI is building the project I've got this error:

```
✗ Compile Storyboard file LaunchScreen.storyboard (12902 ms)
/Users/travis/build/GabrielMassana/ProjectName/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard:XuA-eV-9XL: error: Launch screens may not use instances of IBUISceneExitPlaceholder.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Travis is using an old version of Xcode here.

To solve the problem I'm forcing the Travis Xcode to be version 7.2 with this line in the `.travis.yml` file:

```
osx_image: xcode7.2
```

So my final `.travis.yml` file is:

My `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: objective-c

osx_image: xcode7.2

script: 
    xctool -project ProjectName. xcodeproj -scheme ProjectName build -sdk iphonesimulator
```

So finally:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED ** (13604 ms)
```

[I also wrote a post in my blog about Travis-CI.](https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/05/add-travis-ci-to-your-coding-challenge/)